# How can I overload the __repr__ method to display all items in a linked list Stack?

Tags: python, python-3.x, singly-linked-list

I've created my Node and Stack classes, but I can't figure out how I can display the **repr** in the Stack class in order to be able to print all items currently in the stack? I've been trying to concatenate the nodes but I'm not sure how since the Stack() doesn't allow iterating through the way a list does?

The stack works as it should, I just don't know how to display it's contents?

Here is my code:

```
class Stack:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, elem, next):
            self.elem = elem
            self.next = next
        
        def __repr__(self):
            return str(self.elem)
    
    def __init__(self):
        self._stack = None
        self._size  = 0
        
    
    def __repr__(self):
        # *Not sure how to implement this properly*
        s = ''
        for i in range(self._size):
            last = self._stack.elem
            s += (str(last))+ ', '
            self._stack.elem = self._stack.next
        return 
    
    def push(self, elem):
        if self._stack == None:
            self._stack = self.Node(elem, None)
            self._size += 1 
        else: 
            self._stack = self.Node(elem, self._stack)
            self._size += 1 
    
    def pop(self):
        if self._stack == None:
            raise Exception ('This Stack is empty!')
        else: 
            last = self._stack.elem
            self._stack = self._stack.next
            self._size -= 1
        return last
    
    def top(self):
        return  self._stack.elem
    
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self._size == 0
```

Example:

```
s= Stack()
s.push(4)
s.push(9)
s.push("joe")
s
joe, 9, 9,
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm going to note that typically, the `repr` of a Python class instance is something you could paste back into the interpreter to recreate an equivalent instance. If you want to produce a canonical `repr`, you should probably allow your class to be constructed by passing an iterable to it, not just created empty and populated item by item. Similarly, your `Node` `repr` should almost certainly be using the `repr` of the contained item, not the `str` form (omitting `"Node()"` being okay given `Node` is an implementation detail).

Comment: You shouldn't be using instance variables in your loops, they should just be local variables. Instance variables are for permanent state of the object.

Comment: I don't think a call to `_repr_` should change the stack.

Comment: you need to change `return` to `return s`.

Comment: In your current implementation of `__repr__`, you actually modify `self._stack.elem` - that's a side effect you don't want. Also, you shouldn't use names like `next` as they will shadow the Python built-in `next`; additionally, although you *can* implement a stack as a linked list, there's no real benefit to it, so you should probably just use a list for internal storage or even just use the existing Python classes for this type of functionality.

Comment: Noted. In this case I would like to print the whole stack that is created using the push methods, so I'm not sure how passing an iterable would work. @ShadowRanger

Comment: @Apparent: You'd just add an argument, `iterable=()` to `__init__`, and as the last thing in `__init__`, do `for x in iterable: self.push(x)`. That means it's *possible* to define a reasonable `repr`; without that, whatever `repr` you produce definitionally can't reproduce an equivalent stack.

Comment: @Grismar yes agreed, this is just an exercise I am looking at from a video explaining linked lists. but they don't go over the __repr__

Answer (score 3):

A way simpler implementation that avoids all the problems and pitfalls of your solution:

```
from typing import Iterable, Any


class Stack:
    def __init__(self, xs: Iterable = None):
        self._items = [] if xs is None else list(xs)

    def push(self, elem: Any):
        self._items.append(elem)

    def pop(self) -> Any:
        return self._items.pop()

    def top(self) -> Any:
        return self._items[-1]

    def isEmpty(self) -> bool:
        return not self._items

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        typename = type(self).__name__
        return f'{typename}({self._items})'

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return ', '.join(str(x) for x in self._items)


s = Stack()
s.push(4)
s.push(9)
s.push("joe")
print(s)
print(repr(s))
```

But note that there's little use to a class like this over just using a list like a stack to begin with.

The output:

```
4, 9, joe
Stack([4, 9, 'joe'])
```

Note that this has the top element at the end, you could reverse it if you like of course.

If you insist on a working `__repr__` for your specific implementation, using `__repr__` as you intend in a non-standard way, something like this would work:

```py
    def __repr__(self):
        p = self._stack
        elems = []
        while p is not None:
            elems.append(p.elem)
            p = p.next
        return ', '.join(elems)
```

But note that there's several other issues with your implementation, other than this not being a correct `__repr__`, as previously pointed out here and in the comments. Your 'node' has a `__repr__` which just returns its element value (which isn't a valid representation at all in most cases); you seem to be using `__repr__` where you're really after `__str__`.

If this were an assignment in programming class, I'm not sure I'd award a passing grade, depending on what the aim was.

Comment: For extra safety, decorate `__repr__` [with `@reprlib.recursive_repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html#reprlib.recursive_repr), so if you push a stack on itself, attempts to show its `repr` don't die in a blaze of infinite recursion. You should be doing this with just about any generalized collection (and arguably for literally any user-defined type that isn't a subclass of an immutable built-in type like `int`, `tuple`, etc. with `__slots__ = ()`, since they could all conceivably, if unwisely, be made to contain themselves).

Comment: Yes I agree using a list object would be simpler. But for this I am trying to use a singly linked list to create the stack.